# jQuery - Why I can't change color with append div

Tags: jquery

Why I can't edit color with append div.

Click button and add new div call 'block2',if using $(this), it will not work.
How to fix it ?

HTML

```
<div id="btn"><input name="click" type="button" value="Click" /></div>
<div class="block1" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:orange;">I am Block1</div>
```

JS

```
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var $newDiv=$('<div class="block2" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:green;">I am Block2</div>');
        $( "#btn").parent().append($newDiv);

    });

$('.block1').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});

$('.block2').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/e7Apx/

Please note you are appending the element hence use API `.on` for the class `.block2` :         `$(document).on('click','.block2',function() { ... });`

API: `.on` *documentation* -> http://api.jquery.com/on/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var $newDiv = $('<div class="block2" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:green;">I am Block2</div>');
        $("#btn").parent().append($newDiv);

    });

    $('.block1').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'blue');
    });

    $(document).on('click','.block2',function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'blue');
    });
});​
```

Comment: And When I continue add more block, just like block3, block4...10,I can't make too much selector just like  $(document).on('click','.block3',function() { ... });

Comment: @user962408 yep,look for chaining concept in Jquery, also - since you are using class use same class on all the elements hence you might not need so many different class **but** I might be missing more context to your work, just gicing you ideas, hope it helps, `:)`

Comment: Thank you for given me inspire !

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working Here..

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fTs4E/1/)

For block2 you need to **delegate** the event as it is dynamically being added..

```
$('body').on('click','.block2' ,function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});​
```

**JS**

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var $newDiv = $('<div class="block2" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:green;">I am Block2</div>');
    $("#btn").parent().append($newDiv);

});

$('.block1').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});

$('body').on('click','.block2' ,function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});​
```